# Mongoose controller cant find a method from Repository

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have my code setup in 3 files: `Search.model.js`, `Search.repository.js`, and `search.controller.js`.

The issue is when I send a request to the Route it reaches the controller but cannot call the function in the Repository. The code is below:

`search.repository.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Search = require('../models/search.model');
const perPage = config.PAGINATION_PERPAGE;

const searchRepository = {
    save: async (data) => {
        console.log("Reached save in Repository");
        try {
            let record = await Search.create(data);
            if (!record) {
                return null;
            }
            return record;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    },
};
module.exports = searchRepository;
```

`search.controller.js`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const searchRepo = "../repositories/search.repository";

class SearchController  {
constructor() {}

async store(req) {
  console.log("Reached Store");
    try{
      let record = await searchRepo.save(req.body);
      if (record) {
        return { status: 200, data: {}, message: "Saved Successfully" };
      } else {
        return { status: 201, data: {}, message: "Unable to save your record. Please try again later." };
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      return { status: 201, data: {}, message: e.message };
    }
}
}
module.exports = new SearchController();
```

The error I get:

```
{
    "status": 201,
    "data": {},
    "message": "searchRepo.save is not a function"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The searchRepo variable in `search.controller.js` is not set to the searchRepository object found in `search.repository.js`. Make sure to export and import that object properly. It is currently only set to a string. Instead, you could use `require` (ex. `require({file_path}).{identifier}` to import it.

Comment: I have exports and imports in place. I also edited the code to show my imports and exports.

Comment: Edited post (not sure if I have to do this, sorry I'm new)

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing searchRepo properly in `search.controller.js` file.

Instead of

```
const searchRepo = "../repositories/search.repository";
```

Do this

```
const searchRepo = require("../repositories/search.repository");
```